# Plank not auto-starting on 22.04 even though it is in Startup Applications

Tags: 22.04, startup-applications, plank

I've just upgraded to 22.04.1 (from 20.04) and the Plank dock is no longer autostarting when I log in.

If I run a `ps -f` then I can see the process running, but there is no dock displayed.

If I `kill -15` the running process and start it again from the terminal (no arguments, just `plank`) the dock appears and it is as it was before the upgrade.

I've checked `dmesg` for errors and can't see any mention of Plank in there.

I've also removed it from Startup Applications and re-added it.. still not auto starting, though.

(I've also checked under the settings menu on the login screen to see if I can reselect `XOrg` rather than the new `Wayland`engine but the only options I have are `Budgie Desktop` and `Ubuntu`.)

Using `loginctl show-session $(awk '/tty/ {print $1}' <(loginctl)) -p Type | awk -F= '{print $2}'` returns `X11`showing that I am already running XOrg anyway...

(As a side note, I also tried forcing XOrg via `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncommenting the `WaylandEnabled=false`line.. but as I say, I was already running under XOrg.)

Comment: Deleted my answer because you showed you are already using Xorg. Add that information to your question. One thing to try is to delay the autostartup a few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per vanadium's suggestion, I resolved this by delaying the start of Plank.

I achieved this by creating a little bash script that takes a single argument for the delay in seconds, then starts plank in the background. I then changed my `Startup Applications` to call this instead of running Plank directly.

I called the script `startPlank` and saved it in the same directory as Plank itself (so that it is found in the path as the original `plank` is) and added execute permissions to the file.

My script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]
then
    sleep $1
fi

plank &
```

And in Startup Applications I now simply call `startPlank 2` instead of just `plank`.

Comment: This worked for me also.  But Startup Applications already had an optional delay feature, so I didn't need the script